# Confusing Problem of Points Explanation

Tags: probability

In K. L. Chung's *Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes*, he writes about the POP problem using a coin toss.

> Each player gains a point when he wins a game, and nothing when he
>   loses. Suppose that they stop playing when A needs 2 more points, and
>   B needs 3 more points to win the stake. How should they divide it
>   fairly?
>
> It is clear that the winner will be decided in 4 more games. For in
>   those 4 games either A will have won $\geq$ 2 points or B will have won
>   $\geq$ 3 points, but not both.

How is it clear that the winner will be decided in 4 games? He JUST said A could have won in 2 games, and B in 3. How could A have won more than 2 points if the game would have stopped at 2 points??? I guess my brain is working today because I cannot figure out what he means.

Generally, I get the POP problem, but this explanation is really bothering me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 more games either A has won 2 or more and achieved victory, or A has won only 1 or less, in which case B has won 3 or more and achieved victory.

Comment: hmm... I see what you're saying. That doesn't explain why it's clear that 4 more games have to be played for a winner to be definitively decided. He says that they stop playing when A needs 2 more points. Which means it's possible, if the game didn't stop, that they would only had to have played 2 more games. It doesn't make any sense!

Comment: There could be a result earlier, but it takes 4 games to be certain there is a result. If only 3 are played maybe A wins 1 and B wins 2.

Comment: Yes! Why couldn't he just say "It's possible the game could be extended at most 4 games" or what you said "it takes 4 games to be certain there is a winner". Much clearer. Thanks Peter. Geeze. I worry about the way my brain works sometimes.